# how to update unity ads above version 4.4.2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

Since version 4.4.2, unity ads cannot be updated via package manager, however, they continue to release unity ads updates and now the latest version is 4.7.1. How can I upgrade to this version?

I tried to find repositories on git hub with this package, but I couldn't find anything useful

Comment: The authentication method may of change to use OAUTH.  See : https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/mediate

Comment: Instead of upgrading, it sounds like you have to remove 4.4.2, then add 4.7.1.

Back up your code before you try anything!

Comment: Dustim_00 I've tried this. I would like to find a valid link to the unity ads 4.7.1 package, there is nothing on the official unity website

Answer (score 0):

Unity is no longer regularly updating the "Unity Ads" plug-in (now called "Unity Advertisement Legacy").  The most recent version released is 4.4.2.

The advertisement SDK versions that you may see that are later than 4.4.2 (4.9 is the latest as of this writing) are only for iOS and Android platforms.

The changelog can be found here:
https://docs.unity.com/ads/en-us/manual/Changelog#Unity_Ads_SDK_changelog

Note the easy to miss Platform column on the left, and how iOS/Android are represented in the latest releases, but you have to go back to 4.4.2 to see Unity listed as a platform.

If anybody knows how to update the SDK within the Unity plug-in, I'd love to hear about it because I'm running into a bug with bannerViewDidShow delegate causing an uncaught exception.  The SDK listed in my log is 4.8 (even though I am using the Unity Advertisement Legacy plug-in version 4.4.2).  On the changelog link I included above, a bug fix is noted for bannerViewDidShow in 4.9!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).